# Calculating probability of Type II Error for a one-sample t test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

So I have the following problem:

A transportation company is suspicious of the claim that the average useful life of certain tires is at least 28,000 miles. To verify that, 40 tires are placed in trucks and an average useful life of 27463 is obtained with a standard deviation of 1348 miles.

a) Test this hypothesis with a level of significance of α = 0.01

b) If $\mu_1 = 27230,$ calculate the probability of Type II Error

Any hint on how to do b)?

Comment: Hey I would reply in an answer but I am on mobile... this link should help. http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~gwallace/PA_818/Resources/Type%20II%20Error%20and%20Power%20Calculations.pdf  Just scroll to the very bottom

Comment: This is for part b

Comment: For part a just do a t-test

Comment: That was definitely helpful, thank you! However, I still don't how the value of σ. I have no idea how to get it

Comment: Use what they gave you. 1348

Comment: Ohh alright, I thought that was the sample deviation, but thanks!

Comment: The link to Wallace at Wisconsin is for finding the power of a z test, not a t test.

Answer (score 1):

**Test of hypothesis:** Testing $H_0: \mu = 28000$ vs $H_a: \mu < 28000,$ based on $n = 40$
observations with $\bar X = 27463$ and $S = 1348,$ we Reject $H_0$
at level 1% because the P-value is less than 1%.

Here are results from Minitab statistical software.

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 28000 vs < 28000

 N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean  99% Upper Bound      T      P
40  27463   1348      213            27980  -2.52  0.008
```

Obviously, 27463 < 28000. The question is whether it is *enough* smaller
that we shouldn't ascribe the difference to random variation. The
answer (from the one-sided 99& CI) is that any sample mean below 27980 would
be significantly smaller.

**Power computation for specified alternative.** Minitab's 'power and sample size' procedure uses the *noncentral* t
distribution to find power given $n,$ the direction of the test,
the difference between null and alternative values, the significance level, and (an estimate
$\hat \sigma = 1348$ of) of $\sigma.$ The Type II Error probability is 1 - Power, so the probability of Type II error is about 0.123.

```
   1-Sample t Test

Testing mean = null (versus < null)
Calculating power for mean = null + difference
α = 0.01  Assumed standard deviation = 1348

            Sample
Difference    Size     Power
      -770      40  0.876884
```

Power computations require a population variance, or at least the speculation of one. Usual practice is to use
a sample variance as an estimate if one is available. If the true
mean endurance of a tire is as low as 27,230, using data from 40 tires
gives us a pretty good (approx. 88%) chance of detecting that the claimed
28,000 is an exaggeration. (Notice that the difference between $\mu_0$
and this $\mu_1$ is more than a couple of standard errors.)

[image]

*Notes:* (1) Depending on the level of your class, the intention of the exercise may have been to treat this as a power
computation for a z test because $n > 30.$ However, the 'rule' that
t and z tests are 'essentially the same' for $n > 30$ is based on
the fact that the critical value for a one-sided test at the *5% level* $t^*$ is close to $z* = 1.645.$ However, for a test at the *1% level* 
the critical value $t_{.01,39} \approx 2.43$ may not be sufficiently
close to the critical value $z_{.01} \approx 2.33.$

(2) In order to do an accurate power computation for a t test, it is necessary
to use the noncentral t distribution, as in Minitab. Many mathematical 
statistics texts have explanations of the noncentral t distribution and
its use in power computations. I found the Wikipedia article to be
unnecessarily technical, but Section 5 of [this paper by Scholz](http://www.stat.washington.edu/fritz/DATAFILES/NoncentralT.pdf) may be helpful.

Comment: Hello, Bruce. Sorry for late comment, but I faced same problem, but with two samples t-test: how can I find type II error, having  samples and t-statistics? Do I need to use non-central t-distribution?

Comment: Exact power computations for one-sample t and pooled 2-sample t test do use noncentral t dist'ns. // Because df for Welch 2-sample t depend on sample variances, simulation is often used. // Do you have a particular computation in mind? If so, say what kind of t test, give sig. level, desired power, difference in means to detect, and estimated variance(s). // I will try to look back here is an hour or two and try to help.

Comment: I made a question with context for convinience, please check it: [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572847/type-i-and-type-ii-errors-for-t-test)

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure out this problem?

Part A) Use a T-test in the graphing calculator

the t-statistic is given by 
$$ t = \frac{\left.\left(\bar{X}-\mu \right.\right)}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

thus,

$$t = -2.5195$$

For a significance level of $.01$, the t-critical value is about $2.425$

If  |t| > t-critical, you can declare statistical significance and reject the null hypothesis

The null hypothesis is $H_0: \mu_ \ge \mu_0,$ and
the alternative hypothesis is $H_a: \mu_ < \mu_0,$

Now to find the actual p-value you can use your graphing calculator

Using T-test in graphing calculator:
$$ P-value = .00798$$
Thus, we have sufficient evidence that the claim "the average useful life of certain tires is at least 28,000 miles" is invalid, it is actually less. $OR$ we have insufficient evidence to conclude that the claim "the average useful life of certain tires is at least 28,000 miles" valid.

**Part B Update, This is what I think it is, based on your most recent comment** 
$$2.326*\frac{1348}{\sqrt{40}} = 495.758$$
and $$28000 - 495.758 = 27504.2$$

Now,

$$\frac{27504.2\, -27230}{\frac{1348}{\sqrt{40}}} =1.286 $$

Type 2 Error = $$1 -P(z > 1.286)$$

Thus, $$1 - .9007785 = .09922$$

OR
$$P(z \leq 1.286) = .09922$$

Comment: Wait I followed the steps given in:

http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~gwallace/PA_818/Resources/Type%20II%20Error%20and%20Power%20Calculations.pdf

And I came up with:


Xcritical = (-2.52)(1348) + 28000 = 24603.04


P((z < 27463−28000)/1348) = P(z < -1.95)


0.9941 = 99.41%

Comment: Ahh I see. Yeah that actually looks good. Do you know if that is right? Like can you check in the back of your textbook or no?? I will get rid of my answer for part B.

Comment: It isn't on any textbook but tomorrow I'll talk to my professor to figure out the answer & I'll make sure to post it here. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sounds great, now I'm curious. You're welcome!

Comment: For one-sided t test in Minitab, I got  $T = -2.52$ and $P-value  0.008.$
To get the power of a t test, you need to use the noncentral t distribution. For a power computation you'd need to make a guess at pop SD $\sigma.$ Usual to use sample SD $S$ as an estimate of $\sigma$ for lack of better info. Power is 1 - P(Type II Err). Many software packages have a programmed procedure for finding power.

Comment: So it might be a little late but I did ended up figuring out this problem, I think. b) Xcritical = ((-2.326)(1348/√40)) + 28000 = 27504.24214, then z > (27504.24214 - 27230) / (1348/√40), equals 1 - (z<1.29), which is 1 - (z<0.9015) = 0.0985, so P(Type II Error) = 9.85%, at least I think that's it

Comment: @ACZepp Just not sure where you got z<.9015 from

Comment: @ACZepp OHH I see whats wrong. Ok so P(z < 1.29) = .9015, not P(z <1.29) = P(z<.9015) because the .9015 is the area under the curve for P(z<1.29).. Its just a notation error I didn't see. Ok it looks great. Good job!

Comment: Yes, that's it! But hey, thank you very much for all of this, without your lead I probably wouldn't have solved it! Thanks!

Comment: @ACZepp No problem, glad I could be of help! I will look out for your username and help when I can. Take care.